# Generating commands based on a value from a column - sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table ID_DATA with below records

### _id _data

```
3   test
5   tested
```

I need to generate a insert sql like below

```
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('test');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('test');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('test');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('tested');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('tested');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('tested');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('tested');
insert into ID_DATA_QURY values ('tested');
```

Output should be based on the value in _ID first 3 insert are based on value 3 and data "test" next is 5 on "tested"

Need your help or an example to start with.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Both will work sql server is preferable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQL Server 2008 you can use the `CROSS APPLY` table operator:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @T 
SELECT 3, 'Test' UNION
SELECT 5, 'Tested'

SELECT 'insert into ID_DATA_QURY values (' + T.DATA + ');' AS Command
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT N
             FROM (SELECT 1 AS N UNION
                   SELECT 2 UNION
                   SELECT 3 UNION
                   SELECT 4 UNION
                   SELECT 5) AS I
             WHERE N <= T.ID) AS M
ORDER BY T.ID;
```

**UPDATE:**

Otherwise use this in previous version of SQL Server (should work on MySQL too):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, DATA VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @I TABLE (N INT)
INSERT INTO @T (ID, DATA)
VALUES (3, 'Test')
      ,(5, 'Tested')

-- You can replace it with a table filled with integer numbers.
INSERT INTO @I (N)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

SELECT 'insert into ID_DATA_QURY values (' + T.DATA + ');' AS Command
FROM @T AS T
CROSS JOIN (SELECT N
            FROM @I) AS M
WHERE N <= T.ID
ORDER BY T.ID;
```

Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks let me try that. But my values are in thousands i cannot fix a variable.

Comment: @Machha You can create a table with integer numbers and use it instead of the subquery.

Comment: Use `CROSS JOIN` instead of `CROSS APPLY` and just move the predicate `WHERE N <= T.ID` to the outer query and this will work for MySQL too.

Comment: Also, if using SQL Server 2008 specific it is less verbose and cheaper, to take advantage of a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx) rather than `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2...` You can simply use - `INNER JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) i (N) ON i.N <= t.ID` - @Machha for further information on the table of integers see [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)